# Is there any specific index for identifiying settlements in remote areas through Landsat or Sentinel images?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, sentinel-2

I am trying to identify (especially) small settlements in Nigeria that have no electrification. So is there any index that could help me detect households from Landsat or Sentinel images?

Comment: Check Normalized Difference Built-Up Index. Considering small settlements, I think Landsat resolution is too big to detect boundaries. Maybe Sentinel-2 could help you, but for 10m resolution you only have R-G-B-NIR, so you can apply directly and index who consider SWIR bands.

Comment: Could you please supply an example of the type of settlement you are after? This sounds more like a feature extraction/classification problem. Best to use a machine learning algorithm in conjunction with an index rather than an index alone.

Comment: There are small, undocumented remote settlements in Nigeria. We are trying to detect all of the unelectrified ones. This would be one example (however this is a really small one): lat 11.339818° long  5.117657°